How do you fix the labels on the standard Screen Flow Address Component
Does anyone know how to remove the 'Zip'  reference from the label on the Screen Flow address component, and align the fields? Seems a simple thing to expect to be able to do but so far -- no joy.


I am unable to reproduce your misalignment of the fields in your screenshot. Also, mine is ordered differently.
For the generic address component there is no way for you to change the labels unfortunately, but depending on where you want to save the address information, you can change that address's labels.
For example, let us take the Account Billing Address:

Go to Setup
Search for Rename Tabs and Labels
Click "Edit" next to Account
Scroll to the relevant Field and change its label i.e. Billing Zip/Postal Code to just Billing Postal Code


Now you can add the Billing Address for the Account on the Screen element in your flow and the labels will display as you have changed them:

Debugging the Screen Flow shows the difference between the generic address component and the one pulled from the Account Object:

Good luck!
